# AutoCompleteField for Blackberry 4.2

Tags: blackberry

I have to create an `AutoCompleteField` for supporting blackberry OS 4.2. Below is the screen shots i have attached. I have refereed the blackberry SDK, and `AutoCompleteField` is available from 5.0 onwards, and i have done it too, but i have to do it for 4.2 SDK. Here are my requirements for the Blackberry device 4.2 and higher.

1. `AutoCompleteField`  with populating the list of the available values for  selection. On selection of a particular value it should update the selected item value in the label field below.
2. The `AutoCompleteField` should allow only to enter digits.

[image]

Anyone please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an easy thing. You can achieve similar functionality by adding an `EditField` and immediately below it a `ListField`. To emulate the behavior, you must:
-Limit/filter the kind of characters (numeric in your case)
-For each typed char, generate a list of candidate words (this is entirely up to you).
-Once a char is typed, populate the listfield with the available options. Also when a char is deleted (actually each time the text changes).
-When the focus leaves the text field without having selected anything, delete all elements in list field. The same when the user selects a choice. The list should only contain elements when the user is typing.

To detect user input you can use a `TextFilter`, and set it with `editfield.setTextFilter()`. You might also need to extend both `EditField` and `ListField` to do custom painting and give the best possible look.

NOTE: this approach is somehow improvised as you can see. Should I do a similar thing, I don't believe I could come up with anything visually decent. You can also create your own custom field from scratch, but the difficulty is even greater.